# Using anonymous generic types with multiple generics

Tags: c#, generics, types, anonymous-types

After reviewing this [blog](http://kirillosenkov.blogspot.com/2008/01/how-to-create-generic-list-of-anonymous.html) by Kirill Osenkov (How to create a generic List of anonymous types?) I am trying to do something a little more advanced and having issues.

The following code compiles:

```
    var anon = new { One = "1", Two = "2" };
    var result = DoSomething(anon);

    public static T DoSomething<T>(T value)
    {
        return value;
    }
```

But if I try to add an additonal generic type, I cannot get it to build:

```
    var anon = new { One = "1", Two = "2" };
    var result = DoSomethingElse<int>(anon);

    public static T2 DoSomethingElse<T, T2>(T value)
        where T2 : new()
    {
        return new T2();
    }
```

Since I have no way of specifiying that T is typeof(anon), I can't seem to get it to infer this when given a type for T2. Is this possible?

Comment: How do you plan on using the `T value` in your code?  You may be able to just use `object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  This type of feature is not supported by the C# compiler.  You must either manually specify all generic parameters or none and rely on type inference.

The closest you'll get is the following

```
var anon = new { One = "1", Two = "2" };
var result = DoSomethingElse(anon,42);

public static T2 DoSomethingElse<T, T2>(T value, T2 otherValue)
    where T2 : new()
{
    return new T2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really a satisfying answer, but you could do the following, if you can tolerate writing a different version of `DoSomethingWithT2` for each type `T2`:

```
var anon = new { One = "1", Two = "2" };
var result = DoSomethingWithInt(anon);

public static int DoSomethingWithInt<T>(T value)
{
    return DoSomethingElse<T, int>(value);
}

public static T2 DoSomethingElse<T, T2>(T value) where T2 : new()
{
    return new T2();
}
```

The correct-est answer is just to stop using an anonymous type here and use a tuple or define your own type.  Sorry.